# Ajax load content with jquery (URL trigger)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load

I'm trying to create a demo bar just like wordpress theme companies do
.So far, i was able to achieve a bit of it with

```
$('#window').load('index.php?action=theme&themeID=5');
```

Now i want to be able to create specific URLs which trigger specific code.
For example, the above mentioned code runs if i go to

```
http://mysite.com/theme.php?id=5
```

How do i do that? is there any way to do the same with php?

Comment: read php manual [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily done with PHP, you just have to echo the `$_GET['id']` value inside your script:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#window').load('index.php?action=theme&themeID=".$_GET['id']."');</script>";
```

**or**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#window').load('index.php?action=theme&themeID=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>');
</script>
```

[**Reference**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

And yes, `GET` parameters are unsafe, just as `POST` parameters may also be manipulated. You should valid to check if the parameter being passed is valid in your `PHP` page beforing echoing it directly to your script.

Comment: So what exactly does `$_GET[id]` fetches? it sounds like form

Comment: As pryak just said, read the [php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). It'll fetch the `GET` parameter being passed to your page.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$_GET['id']`? With PHP you never know though :).

Comment: You're perfectly right @Mosselman, associative Arrays indexes must be quoted in either single `'` or double `"` quotes as they're strings. Fixed that a couple mins ago. My bad, too sleepy.

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather you are trying to dynamically change javascript based on the url of the page?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#window').load('index.php?action=theme&themeID=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>');
</script>
```

You might want to cast the value to an int or something though in order to secure things a bit.